# Please tell me the meaning of the description in the launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't understand the meaning of the following description(value) in the launch file.
I couldn't understand a description that combines eval, if and else.

```
<arg name="uf_traj_controller" value="$(eval 'lite6_traj_controller_velocity' if arg('velocity_control') else 'lite6_traj_controller')" />
```

Please tell me the meaning of description of value.

A part of launch file

```
<launch>   
  <arg name="run_demo_traj" default="false"/>
  <arg name="effort_control" default="false"/>
  <arg name="velocity_control" default="false"/>
  <arg name="namespace" default="ufactory"/>
  <arg name="add_gripper" default="false" />

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <!-- Load trajectory controller for xArm by default -->
  <rosparam unless="$(arg run_demo_traj)" file="$(find xarm_controller)/config/lite6_traj_controller.yaml" command="load" ns="$(arg namespace)"/>
  <arg name="uf_traj_controller" value="$(eval 'lite6_traj_controller_velocity' if arg('velocity_control') else 'lite6_traj_controller')" />
  <node unless="$(arg run_demo_traj)"
    name="traj_controller_spawner"
    pkg="controller_manager"
    type="controller_manager"
    respawn="false"
    output="screen"
    ns="/$(arg namespace)"
    args="spawn $(arg uf_traj_controller) joint_state_controller"/>

  <!-- run_demo: load the position controllers -->
  <rosparam if="$(arg run_demo_traj)"
    file="$(find xarm_controller)/config/lite6_position_controllers.yaml" command="load" ns="$(arg namespace)"/>
  <node if="$(arg run_demo_traj)" name="position_controller_spawner"
    pkg="controller_manager"
    type="spawner"
    respawn="false"
    output="screen"
    ns="/$(arg namespace)"
    args="joint1_position_controller joint2_position_controller
          joint3_position_controller joint4_position_controller
          joint5_position_controller joint6_position_controller
          joint_state_controller"/>


</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411038/please-tell-me-the-meaning-of-the-description-in-the-launch-file/) by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2023-01-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-01-07**:\

> if arg('velocity_control') else ...

I didn't test it, but I do not think this reads the variable. I'd have written it: `$(arg velocity_control)`

Update: nope, looks like I'm wrong. According to https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML inside an eval the syntax is different, so this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question solved.
When I run the following command,

```
roslaunch xarm_gazebo lite6_beside_table.launch
```

I got the following result.

```
Started ['lite6_traj_controller'] successfully
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
```

When I run the following command,

```
roslaunch xarm_gazebo lite6_beside_table.launch velocity_control:=true
```

I got the following result.

```
Started ['lite6_traj_controller_velocity'] successfully
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
```

Thank you for your reply.

---

Originally posted by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) with karma: 27 on 2023-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's look at the top of the file

```
 <arg name="velocity_control" default="false"/>
```

I think that if you launch with a "velocity_control" at value true, your controller launched will be "lite6_trajectory_controller_velocity", but a default launch will launch "lite6_trajectory_controller"

Your value is evaluated according to the condition, thus mixing eval, if and else

---

Originally posted by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) with karma: 71 on 2023-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Renox](https://answers.ros.org/users/106378/renox/) on 2023-01-04**:
Thank you for your reply.
At first, I thought that if I input velocity_controller at value true, "lite6_traj_controller_velocty" in "lite6_traj_controller.yaml" will launch.

But your description is that if "velocity_controller" at value default(=false), lite6_traj_controller_velocity will launch, not "lite6_traj_controller(position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController)".

I feel conflicted now....(velocity_controller true, but position_controllers/JTC launch?)

A part of "lite6_traj_controller.yaml"

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  <abbreviation>
lite6_traj_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  <abbreviation>
lite6_traj_controller_velocty:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  <abbreviation>
```

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2023-01-04**:
Well, code doesn't lie, sometime our interpretation does.
Do you have the possibility to launch the system with and without argument, and list controllers launched to check which one is running?